# Container iteration (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, iterator, containers

My question can be split into two parts:

1. Is there any advantage in using a shorter integer variable (e.g. short or unsigned char) to loop over array (or stl container) indexes; and
2. What are the advantages (if any) of using iterators with stl containers.

Code example for problem 1:

```
const size_t a=100000000;
const unsigned char b=5;
float array[a][b];

for (size_t j=0; j<a; ++j)
  for (unsigned char i=0; i<b; ++i)
    std::cout << array[j][i] << std::endl;
```

Does using unsigned char in the `i`-loop save me anything? Does `array[j][i]` implicitly cast `i` into a `size_t`?

Code example for problem 2:

```
vector<float> a(1000,0.);
vector<float> b(a);

for (size_t i=0; i<a.size(); ++i)
  cout << a[i] << endl;

for (vector<float>::iterator it=b.begin(); it!=b.end(); ++it)
  cout << *it << endl;
```

Is there an advantage in using the iterator approach? If not in this case, then when? And Why?

Bonus question:
In `for (size_t i=0; i<a.size(); ++i)`, is `a.size()` re-evaluated every time? Do I win anything by getting the size first?

```
const size_t size = a.size();
for (size_t i=0; i<size; ++i)
```

Does `std::vector` simply return the value of a member variable when I call `vector::size()` or does it do something more elaborate?

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: To question 1: No, using the native word size of your processor is more likely to give you a better performance than using shorter integer values.